# fading in li's with alternate colours

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to fade in 10 bullet points, I have made them all list items and the colours need to alternate back and fourth between red and blue. I have achived the speed of the fade in, but can't thick of a way to switch the colours so that it fades in. Plus it gets getter! they need to turn black once faded in!

```
var $ul = $('ul');
var $lis = $('.green-bullets');
var $red = $('ul li.red');
var $blue = $('ul li.blue');

$($lis).hide();


var i = 0;
 (function bulletFadein() {
    $lis.eq(i++).fadeIn('slow', bulletFadein);
 })();
```

Comment: Please explain your goal in more details. Providing your HTML might help. It's hard to know what you are trying to do right now. Do you want your `li`s to fade in and out indefinitely? Do they need to change color, or class?

Comment: not clear enogh to be answered, plz elaborate

Comment: sorry, you're right. I need to fade in a list of 10 li items. They will fade in one after the other from top to bottom, alternating between red and blue. So an example.... 1st li fades in (text red) then 1 second later 2nd li fades in (text blue), then 3rd fades in (text red) again etc etc. but all text will turn black and stay black after the initial fade in has finished.

Comment: Like [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/r810wu7f/)?

Comment: There is a slight flicker when loading it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is quite simple.

First off, if you need to add a transition to the `li`'s. This can be achieved in two ways.

1. ```
   li{
       -webkit-transition: 1s;
       -moz-transition: 1s;
       transition: 1s;
   }
   ```

or

2.

```
    .class{
        -webkit-transition: 1s;
        -moz-transition: 1s;
        transition: 1s;
    }
```

where `class` is the class applied to the specific `li` tags.

Secondly, the javascript. The code for the alternating is:

```
    var liList = document.getElementsByClassName("class"); //Where class is the class of the li's.
    for(var i = 0; i < liList.length; i++){
        if(i & 1){
            liList[i].style.color = "#FF0000"; //Red
        }else{
            liList[i].style.color = "#0000FF"; //Blue
        }
    }
```

And to change it to black once it is faded:

```
    ...FADING CODE...
    ...ALTERNATION CODE...
    setTimeout(function(){
        for(var i = 0; i < liList.length; i++){
            liList[i].style.color = "#000000";  //Black
        }
    },600);
```

What the first part is doing (the alternator) is going through the `.class` class, using an index, and if the index is even, setting the color to blue, and otherwise, turning it to red.

What the second part is doing is simmilar, but once the actual fade completes (after 600ms), changing all of the text to black.

Using the `li`'s transition, this will be smooth.

Comment: That looks ideal and I understand it first time at looking! Getting better haha! thanks